# cocoa document with many files generated a bit at a time

Tags: cocoa, simulation, nsdocument

I've a problem with a document-based project in Cocoa. I've searched for a while but I didn't find anything which seems to resemble my goal. What I want to do is a (computation intensive) simulation program which generates a lot of data (probably in the order of GBs) and store them to the disk for a future visualization (so I cannot write/read the files all at once).

I created a document-based project (I don't know if it is the way to go...) with the idea to save all the data in many binary-files within a package, so the user can see it as a single file. I have already tried that part and I was able to save the document with NSFileWrapper. But the simulation-files are generated as the simulation is running. And here comes the problem.
There is a way to force the user to save the document and retrieve the path so I can put there all the files generated? Or it's best to save the simulation-files in a temporary location and then save the document periodically so that it saves all the files ready for saving? Or what can I do? It's not clear to me the usage of the nsdocument architecture in this case and what it's a good way to achieve my goal.

The document has also another couple of files in which there are the simulation parameters and the initial state, so I can resume the simulation at a later time.